# Google maps failing to load from clicking a button

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to load a google maps activity by clicking a button in the main activity but the map does not load, all that loads is a blank activity with the zoom controls. Below is my code:

MainActivity

```
package com.maplocator.shareplaces;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }


    public void onClick(View view) {
        startActivity(new Intent("com.maplocator1.ToMap"));
        }

    public void Map(final View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,ToMap.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }



}
```

MapActivity

```
package com.maplocator.shareplaces;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ToMap extends FragmentActivity {

    private static final int GPS_ERRORDIALOG_REQUEST = 9001;
    GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (servicesOK()) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Ready to Map", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            setContentView(R.layout.activity_map );
        }
        else {
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        }


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public boolean servicesOK() {
        int isAvailable = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);

        if (isAvailable == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            return true;
        }
        else if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(isAvailable)) {
            Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(isAvailable, this, GPS_ERRORDIALOG_REQUEST);
            dialog.show();
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Can't connect to Google Play services", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static int getGpsErrordialogRequest() {
        return GPS_ERRORDIALOG_REQUEST;
    }

}
```

ActivityMain

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="153dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/share_p"
        android:src="@drawable/shareplaces" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_showmap"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="137dp"
        android:text="@string/go_to_map"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" 
        android:onClick="onClick"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

MapActivity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay the fix to this is actually simple. I was usin an API Key I had made in another application, so to fix this issue all I had to do was go to the Google Apis console and get a key for this new application I was developing, so make sure that you generate a new key for a new application.